# No route matches [POST] "/downtowns/1/properties/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, simple-form

I have an application that has a one to many relationship with downtowns and properties.  What i've been having trouble with is creating new properties from the downtowns.  I keep getting the error that I used as the title for this question.

I have a hunch that the problem is in my form, (which i'm using the simple form gem). I'm able to go to my `new` page, fill out the form, and then when I hit submit, I get this error.

I'll display my form file first. (I've had trouble understanding simple form's docs, and that's why i think this is where the problem is)

```
= simple_form_for (@property), method: 'POST', url: new_downtown_property_path do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :last_remodel
  = f.input :original_construction_year
```

My routes file

```
resources :downtowns do
  resources :properties
end
```

My downtown controller

```
def show
    @properties = Property.where(downtown: @downtown_id)
  end

  def new
    @downtown = Downtown.new
  end

  def create
    @downtown = Downtown.create(downtown_params)
    if @downtown.save
      redirect_to @downtown
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def downtown_params
    params.require(:downtown).permit(:name, :city)
  end
```

and my properties controller

```
  def new
    @property = Property.new
  end

  def create
    @downtown = property.find(id)
    @property = Property.create(params[:property_params])
    @property.downtown_id = @downtown.id

    if @property.save
      redirect_to @property
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
= simple_form_for([@downtown, @property]) do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :last_remodel
  = f.input :original_construction_year
```

Just pass an array to look up the nested route with the polymorphic route helpers. This will correctly use `downtown_properties_path` as the action. In Rails you always create resources by posting to the collection path (`/downtowns/1/properties`). The new route just renders a form. You don't need to specify the method as Rails detects if the model has been persisted and sets the method to POST or PATCH accordingly.

You should also never add a space between the method name and the parens surrounding the argument list in Ruby:

```
def add(a,b)
  a + b
end

add (1, 2) # syntax error
add (1), 2 # this is what actually happens
```

Ruby behaves very differently then for example JS here since parens are optional for method calls.

Your controller is also completely off. A nested resource controller should look something like.

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_downtown
  before_action :set_property, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /downtowns/1/properties/new
  def new
    @property = @downtown.properties.new
  end

  # POST /downtowns/1/properties
  def create
    @property = @downtown.properties.new(property_params)
    if @property.save
      redirect_to @property 
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # ...

  private

  def set_downtown
    @downtown = Downtown.includes(:properties).find(params[:downtown_id])
  end

  def set_propery
    @property = Property.find(params[:id])
  end

  def property_params
    params.require(:downtown)
          .permit(:name, :city)
  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: This is very very helpful! I truly do appreciate you taking a look at this and sharing your wisdom!  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You want to post to the `downtown_property_path` not the `new_downtown_property_path`.

More reading here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

"/downtowns/1/properties/new" is route define when you render the template to create the record and its verb is GET instead.

In the form, the path you need is URL that route to handle POST action, and action needs to handle it I think it is "properties#create" and if you want to use URL correct URL is "downtown_properties_path". You can run "rails routes" command to get the detail.